# Hash symbol after define macro?

Tags: c++, c, preprocessor, stringification

What does the '#' symbol do after the second define? And isn't the second line enough? Why the first one?

```
#define MAKESTRING(n) STRING(n)
#define STRING(n) #n
```

Comment: [Stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/cpp/Stringification.html)

Comment: You probably want to stay away from this in C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is stringize operation, it will produce a string literal from macro parameter, e.g. `"n"`. Two lines are required to allow extra expantion of macro parameter, for example:

```
// prints __LINE__ (not expanded)
std::cout << STRING(__LINE__) << std::endl;
// prints 42 (line number)
std::cout << MAKESTRING(__LINE__) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hash symbol takes macro argument into a c-string.
For example

```
#define MAKESTRING(x) #x
printf(MAKESTRING(text));
```

will print `text`

And first line is only alternative name for this macro.

Comment: It's not an alternative name: the argument wouldn't be expanded otherwise.