# Use of '#' in unexpected way

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

There's a macro defined as:

```
#define SET_ARRAY(field, type) \
  foo.field = bar[#field].data<type>();
```

`foo` is a structure with members that are of type `int` or `float *`.  `bar` is of type `cnpy::npz_t` (data loaded from .npz file).  I understand that the macro is setting the structure member pointer so that it is pointing to the corresponding data in `bar` from the .npy file contained in the .npz file, but I'm wondering about the usage `bar[#field]`.

When I ran the code through the preprocessor, I get:

```
foo.struct_member_name = bar["struct_member_name"].data<float>();
```

but I've never seen that type of usage either.  It looks like the struct member variable name is somehow getting converted to an array index or memory offset that resolves to the data within the `cnpy::npz_t` structure.  Can anyone explain how that is happening?

Comment: Look for `operator[]()` in `bar`'s type.

Comment: First hit on "cnpy::npz_t" brings me to [`using npz_t = std::map<std::string, NpyArray>;`](https://github.com/rogersce/cnpy/blob/master/cnpy.h#L63") for which using `operator[](std::string)` would make perfect sense. The `#` token is of course just a stringification operator of the preprocessor

Comment: *but I've never seen that type of usage either* -- [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/z1Kba9Pb7)

Comment: Why is there a macro in the first place? Try to avoid macros : This can be perfectly handled by a template function. [ES.31: Don’t use macros for constants or “functions”](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es31-dont-use-macros-for-constants-or-functions)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Can it? How do *you* get a `std::string` from the name of a data member?

Comment: It sounds like you've skipped over the first half or so of your C++ book.

Comment: @Botje, good thinking.  I should have thought about operator overloading.  I did say my C++ is very rusty.  :)

Comment: Actually, I hadn't noticed that my post had been edited to remove my warning about my C++ being very rusty.  Thanks all for the help!

Comment: Here is an explanation of what @Botje was talking about stringification from '#' 
 [replace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hash symbol after define macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464253/hash-symbol-after-define-macro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#` is actually a preprocessor marker. That means preprocessor commands (not functions), formally called "preprocessor directives", are being executed at compile time. Apart from commands, you'll also find something akin to constants (meaning they have predefined values, either static or dynamic - yes I used the term constants loosely, but I am oversimplifying this right now), but they aren't constants "in that way", they just seem like that to us.

A number of preprocessor commands that you will find are:
`#define`, `#include`, `#undef`, `#if` (yes, different from the normal "if" in code), `#elif`, `#endif`, `#error` - all those must be prefixed by a "#".

Some values might be the `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, `__cplusplus` and more. These are not prefixed by #, but can be used in preprocessor macros. The values are dynamically set by the compiler, depending on context.

For more information on macros, you can check the [MS Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-160) page for MSVS or the [GNU](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Predefined-Macros.html) page for GCC. For other preprocessor values, you can also see [this SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/) page.

And of course, you can define your own macro or pseudo-constants using the `#define` directive.

```
#define test_integer 7
```

Using test_integer anywhere in your code (or macros) will be replaced by 7 after compilation. Note that macros are case-sensitive, just like everything else in C and C++.

Now, let's talk about special cases of "#":

- string-izing a parameter (also called "to stringify")

  What that means is you can pass a parameters and it is turned into a string, which is what happened in your case. An example:

  ```
  #define NAME_TO_STRING(x) #x

  std::cout << NAME_TO_STRING(Hello) << std::endl;
  ```

  This will turn **Hello** which is NOT a string, but an identifier, to a string.
- concatenating two parameters

  ```
  #define CONCAT(x1, x2)          x1##x2
  #define CONCAT_STRING(x1, x2)   CONCAT(#x1,#x2)
  #define CONCATENATE(x1, x2)     CONCAT_STRING(x1, x2)
  ```

  (yes, it doesn't work directly, you need a level of indirection for preprocessor concatenation to work; indirection means passing it again to a different macro).

  ```
  std::cout << CONCATENATE(Hello,World) << std::endl;
  ```

  This will turn **Hello** and **World** which are identifiers, to a concatenated string: **HelloWorld**.

Now, regarding usage of # and ##, that's a more advanced topic. There are many use cases from macro-magic (which might seem cool when you see it implemented - for examples, check the Unreal Engine as it's extensively used there, but be warned, such programming methods are not encouraged), helpers, some constant definitions (think #define TERRA_GRAV 9.807) and even help in some compile-time checks, for example using constexpr from the newest standards.

If you're curious what is the advantage of using `#define` versus a `const float` or `const double`, it might also be to not be part of the code (there is no actual syntax check on macros if they are not used).

In regards to helper macros, the most common are defining exports when building a library (search `__declspec` for MSVS and `__attribute__` for GCC), the old style inclusion limitators (now replaced by `#pragma` once) to stop a *.h, *.hxx or *.hpp from being included multiple times in projects and debug handling (search for `_DEBUG` and assertions on Google). This paragraph handles slightly more advanced topics so I won't cover them here.

I tried to keep the explanation as simple as possible, so the terminology is not that formal. But if you really are curious, I am sure you can find more details online or you can post a comment on this answer :)